# Runtime error while using %arg marco in NASM

Tags: segmentation-fault, runtime-error, nasm

```
    extern printf
    section .text
    
    global add_one
add_one:
    %push func_addone
    %stacksize flat64
    %arg a:qword
    inc qword [a]
    mov rax, [a]
    ret
    %pop
    
    global main
main:
    mov rcx, 1
    sub rsp, 28h
    call add_one
    add rsp, 28h
    mov rcx, format
    mov rdx, rax
    sub rsp, 28h
    call printf
    add rsp, 28h
    xor rax, rax
    ret

    section .data
format:
    db "number: %d", 10, 0
```

My Env: cpu x86_64, windows 10, NASM 2.11.02, linking with MINGW64 GCC 4.8.1.

I am a beginer to NASM. I wants to implament a program calculate 1 add 1 and output.

I tried to call `add_one` function following windows's x64 calling convention by moving the first argument into *rax* and reserving 32 bytes of *shadow storage* (I actually reserved 40 bytes to align rsp to 16). This calling method works when I tried to call functions like `puts`. But this program abort with *segmentation fault* after about 1.5 seconds without outputing anything.

I'm not a native English speaker, so sorry to my grammer mistakes.